# Level of exactness of Na'"ch

Tags: tanach, theology, nevua-prophecy

1. Torah was [dictated](https://www.aish.com/h/sh/tat/48969731.html) by G-d to Moses and is exact by letter.
2. Mishnah and Gemmorah (and all subsequent books) are man-made and written loosely (at least not letter-exact - see תנא ושייר and more).

The tradition says that the books of Na"ch were written by people with Ruach Hakodesh, not strictly dictated by G-d. [*@Loewian suggested to differentiate between Prophets and Writings as they don't share the same level of ... something*]

In what category of exactness do the books of Na"ch fall?

Comment: the middle one.

Comment: Also, *sifrei neviim* were written *b'nevuah* (prophetically), not just with the *ruach hakodesh* (divine inspiration) of *kethuvim*.

Comment: @Loewian So was the book of Yehoshua *dictated* to Yehoshua in prophecy or ti someone else?

Comment: It seems pretty accepted that none of the books of the prophets were "dictated" to the prophets, at least inasmuch as prophecy is traditionally described as experiential for the prophet rather than verbal (see e.g. Maharal's first introduction to Gevuroth Hashem).

Comment: @Loewian Please continue - so what level of exactness do those prophecies exhibit?

Comment: Presumably not as much as the Pentateuch; probably more than Writings, which, in turn, are presumably more precise than subsequent and/or lesser Torah scholars...

Comment: @Loewian I added your point to the Q.

Comment: I think the overlap with https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105507/how-a-prophet-translates-a-vision-into-words/105526#105526 is great enough to warrant combining them into 1 Q.